# Android AppBar with Framelayout as Fragment Container

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, android-framelayout

I'm facing a problem that I am not capable to solve. If someone could provide me with a quick solution this will make my day. 
As you can see in the picture attached the FrameLayout is not below the AppBar. I am using the FrameLayout as a container for Fragments. So what I want to achieve is that the FrameLayout is right below the AppBar. I guess I can achieve this with a margin but I think this is not the proper solution. 
Best regards and thanks a lot in advance.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.mbcs.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Dont use `CoordinatorLayout` , use `RelativeLayout` and then you can use tags of `layout_below` or `layout_above`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `RelativeLayout` instead

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.mbcs.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_below="appbarId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```